# Edge extruding instead of moving the mesh

Tags: edges, extrude

I am trying to transform an edge, but instead it extrudes as a new plane.

[image]

This only happens to some edges, and vertices, and I don´t understand why or how to make it move the way I want to. Very new to Blender, and help is appreciated

Comment: Try to Remove Doubles. Select All > W > Remove Doubles (in Edit Mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold shift while selecting and then extrude...PS. You need to have at least 1 edge selected for the extrude result not to be a plane!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the slight angle the previous edge has I can assume that you are holding Ctrl while clicking. If you do that a new edge will get extruded from the one you selected.